# converting php scripts into cakephp

Tags: php, jquery, cakephp

Any good resources on this?

Ideally a tutorial or walkthrough of an application being designed from the ground up or even just tutorials on the inns and outs of the framework.

I have a lot of php scripts and jquery is used to update various containers on the page.  I have the Auth Module working and the homepage is displaying, but where do i start in terms of converting all those php scripts into MVC compliant code?

Currently, the majority of my scripts work similar to this example:

```
$.post('/scripts/getUserInfo.php', { id:id },
    function(output){
        $('div#user_info_container').html( output );
    }
);
```

QUESTION:

What are the steps involved in creating MVC compliant code from php scripts? Do you start by writing a controller for each script?

Am relatively new to Cake so any advice appreciated guys...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write one controller and create one action for every script, where  You query data from DB. For each action You will have to add a view with html output from Your previous script.

But it very much depends on Your DB model structure - if Your scripts updates data from different tables, probably You should create actions in apriopiate controllers (connected with that table model).

You can check $this->isAjax() in You controller[s] and change render layout to minimalistic (without page layout)

Comment: ok, so if i have a script that uses say the users table, then do I place the action in the users_controller, or do I create a new controller for that particular script??

Comment: OK, if Your scripts are connected to different tables - put actions in apriopiate controllers and use different layout (like 'ajax') to render such actions

Comment: Ok, thats good advice. If you look at the sample code I posted, how do I connect to a controller from the above code? If you could post a sample that would be great.

Comment: $.post('/users/getinfo', { id:id },
    function(output){
        $('div#user_info_container').html( output );
    }
);

Comment: I would move id parameter into url (more cakeish way): $.post('/users/getinfo/'+id, function(output){ $('div#user_info_container').html( output ); } );